# IIS Under Construction page even with a default page set up

Tags: iis, asp.net

I have a outfacing website under IIS that has a default page currently set up. It matches a site exactly that is currently also outfacing, but it seems the first website won't work and externally shows a "Site Under Construction" page.

I have ensured that I have a default page set up, and even created a new one just in case. Is there anything else that could go wrong and show this holding page? All my pages are ASP.Net just in case it could be to do with a `web.config` error?

Comment: Does the site run on port 80? Does the sire run on it's own ip address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [this post](http://forums.asp.net/t/1959986.aspx?Browser+does+not+recognise+a+website+hosted+on+local+IIS) for the same issue and resolution.

- Check binding hostname
- Check binding IP
- Check binding Port
- Check Default Documents

Note: visiting the 'same' url from inside your network and outside and getting 'different results' indicates that the url is resolving to different IP addresses and that the IIS hostname bindings do not match.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was the different IP, internally it was working correctly, outside we got the Under Construction error. The external was resolving a separate IP address to the internal.